# In Python how the write output of a command into a file

Tags: python

I want to write a python script that should execute multiple commands one by one and the output should be saved into a file in append mode. I tried writing a script, it is working for single command but how to write for multiple command.

```
import subprocess
with open(filename, "a") as output:
    subprocess.Popen('cmd1''cmd2''cmd3', shell=True, stdout=output)
```

For eg:

```
cmd1 = dir
cmd2 = whoami
```

The file should contain the output of both commands one after the other.

Comment: Did you try to create multiple functions and call them one by one ?

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
import subprocess
commands = ['ls','pwd']
with open('cmd_out.txt', "a") as output:
    subprocess.Popen(';'.join(commands), shell=True, stdout=output)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Popen` executes a single command; in your example, you are actually executing `dir` and passing it `whoami` as an argument.

So you need to call `Popen` for each command individually.  Having each append to the same file should produce the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

Separate the commands with `;`:

```
subprocess.Popen('cmd1; cmd2; cmd3', shell=True, stdout=output)
```